# Mysql nested queries take a long time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

We are using the following question to get date out of a large mysql table.

```
SELECT fullPath, Permissiontype, DinstinguishedName 
from cdm.test 
where fullPath in 
  (SELECT distinct fullPath 
   FROMcdm.test 
   WHERE (Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' and not DinstinguishedName ='') 
   OR(Permissiontype = 'INHERITED' 
     AND (length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) < 4)) 
   OR(Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' 
     AND NOT DinstinguishedName='' 
     AND LEFT(fullPath,length(fullPath)-Length(RIGHT(fullPath,INSTR(reverse(fullPath),'/')))) 
AND(length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) > 2) ))
```

When I limit the results that need to be shown to 270 it runs really fast, but for example 500 rows it just doesn't run. I have for 1 case 77mil rows in the table (needs to be in 1 table). And then it runs over 8 hours and still doesn't finish. Is there a way to optimize this?

wkr.

Comment: you could try the exists() statement instead fo your in() statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Comment: I just noticed that my edit pasted one of your from statements together with the table name, might want to fix that (I know I would but that might be because I'm slightly obsessive :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each record in the test table you're querying the entire table again in the subquery. Instead of using a subquery in the where clause, try an inner join on the same table. This will dramatically improve your performance.

I haven't tried it yet but it could look like:

```
SELECT fullPath, Permissiontype, DinstinguishedName from cdm.test 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT distinct fullPath from cdm.test 
where (Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' and not DinstinguishedName ='') 
or (Permissiontype = 'INHERITED' AND (length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) < 4)) OR(Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' 
AND NOT DinstinguishedName='' AND LEFT(fullPath,length(fullPath)-length(RIGHT(fullPath,INSTR(reverse(fullPath),'/')))) 
and(length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) > 2) )
) AS SQ1 
ON SQ1.fullpath = cdm.test.fullpath
```

Comment: Thanks this answer gave the best results in the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

For the combination of IN statement and subqueries mysql has a usefull optimizer called EXISTS() (not specifically meant for this but can be used to optimize queries that use the IN statement in combination with subquery)

According to the reference on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

```
outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ... WHERE subquery_where)
```

Would be the same as

```
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE subquery_where AND outer_expr=inner_expr)
```

But faster

Your query with exist:

```
SELECT fullPath, Permissiontype, DinstinguishedName 
FROM cdm.test cdm1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM cdm.test cdm2 @wherecondition AND cdm2.fullPath = cdm1.fullPath)
```

@wherecondition =

```
WHERE (Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' and not DinstinguishedName ='') 
   OR(Permissiontype = 'INHERITED' 
     AND (length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) < 4)) 
   OR(Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' 
     AND NOT DinstinguishedName='' 
     AND LEFT(fullPath,length(fullPath)-Length(RIGHT(fullPath,INSTR(reverse(fullPath),'/')))) 
AND(length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) > 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues which would make the query execution very slow

1. You are using `in` clause and they are bad in many occasions, so better would be convert them to JOIN clause.
2. Even with the JOIN the inner query has multiple `OR` conditions and  optimizer can not use the indexes for them.
3. Why you need the `in clause` at all ?

The same query could be written as

```
select fullPath,Permissiontype,DinstinguishedName from cdm.test  
    where  
    Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT' 
    and not DinstinguishedName ='' 

    union 
    select fullPath,Permissiontype,DinstinguishedName from cdm.test  
    where Permissiontype = 'INHERITED' 
    AND (length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) < 4)

    union
    select fullPath,Permissiontype,DinstinguishedName from cdm.test 
    where Permissiontype = 'EXPLICIT'  
    AND NOT DinstinguishedName=''   
    AND LEFT(fullPath,length(fullPath)-length(RIGHT(fullPath,INSTR(reverse(fullPath),'/')))) 
    and(length(fullPath) - length(replace(fullPath,'/','')) > 2)
```

Note that I have changed all the `OR` conditions to `union` and this will be faster.

Now add an index if its not added already as

```
alter table cdm.test add index search_data_idx(Permissiontype,DinstinguishedName,fullPath);
```